# mongodb: updateOne set array of string if elements non present, leave unaltered if present

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following document in mongodb:

```
{
    "_id":"43434",
    "mail": "test@gmail.com"
    "category": ["Alimentari","Eventi","Ristorante","Servizi"]
}
```

I would like to write java code so that if:

1. I have the following Array of string in input ["Alimentari","Eventi","Ristorante"], the document remain unchanghed
2. with the following array string ["Alimentari","Bar"] the document will be:

```
{
    "_id":"43434",
    "mail": "test@gmail.com"
    "category": ["Alimentari","Eventi","Ristorante","Servizi","Bar"]
}
```

3. if I pass an array of just one string ["Alimentari"], the document remain unchanghed
4. if I pass the following ["Grande Distribuzione"], the document will be

```
{
    "_id":"43434",
    "mail": "test@gmail.com"
    "category": ["Alimentari","Eventi","Ristorante","Servizi","Grande Distribuzione"]
}
```

I tried with this code

```
    String[] category= {"Alimentari","Eventi","Ristorante"};
    collection.updateOne(
        new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(_id)),
        new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("category", category));
```

but the resulting document is:

```
{
    "_id":"43434",
    "mail": "test@gmail.com"
    "category": ["Alimentari","Eventi","Ristorante"]
}
```

Could you please help me ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB query answer, you need `$addToSet` with [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) to add multiple values into the `category` field if the value doesn't exist.

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "43434"
},
{
  "$addToSet": {
    "category": {
      "$each": [
        "Alimentari",
        "Bar"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KSlrJdeUvKk)